# Can I run a #6 circuit from a subpanel fed by #6 wire?

Tags: wiring

I have a new 100amp rated sub panel, grounded with a new copper rod in my shed 50 feet from main breaker box, with 6/3 as the feeder to the sub panel. I’m installing a hot tub. I do have a 50amp breaker box between the shed and approximately 6 feet away from the tub. Can I use 6/3 to run from my sub panel to the 50 amp breaker box for the hot tub?

I only have 4 outlets I use in my shed all on one 20 amp breaker. I just want to know if I can run power to my hot tub with the 6/3 off my sub panel, with my sub panel being powered by 6/3.

Comment: Is that existing 6/3 feeder direct bury cable (UF), or wires in a conduit of some sort?

Comment: You'll need a GFCI breaker

Comment: 6/3 **with ground**, and properly isolated ground and neutral at the shed? Your description of the grounding concerns me as being potentially 50 years out of date (local ground rod is required for a separate building, but so is a ground connection back to the main panel,  many decades now...

Comment: My shed sub panel is grounded back to the main breaker box, it also has a 8’ copper pounded into the ground at the shed which is also grounded to the sub panel in the shed… 6/3 thwn buried in conduit is what feeds the sub panel in the shed…. I installed a Square D - HOME250SPA Homeline Spa Panel, Load Center With 50-Amp Enclosed Main Breaker, 2-Pole, Ground Fault Interrup 6 feet from where the hot tub will be- my question is, am I ok to use the 6/3 thhn/thwn from the sub panel in the shed to the spa panel I installed which is about 20 ‘ from the shed

Comment: Will that run My tub, or do I need to run the wiring from the spa panel directly to the main house panel?

Comment: I do have 4 outlets in my shed all on a single 20amp breaker, never much use out of the outlets on a continuous basis anyways…

Comment: The spa panel is not between the main panel or the sub panel, basically it’s a horseshoe shape starting at the main, then to the sub and finally to the spa panel- from that point the hot tub company will be completing the hook up of the actual hot tub to the spa panel…

Comment: Also I have a 50amp double pull at main breaker which services the sub panel, & a 50 amp double pull that I can use in the sub panel for the spa panel service, or should I up any of those to 60 amp breakers?

Comment: There's no such thing as 6/3 THWN. THWN is individual wires.  Are you saying there are 4 individual wires with no outer cable jacket, all inside a PVC conduit?   And it's double POLE, pole like pole position,  not pull like a rope.

Comment: I’m using 6awg thhn/thwn in conduit? And I’m sorry I didn’t know this was a spelling class

Comment: While it's not a "spelling class", @user155281, knowing the correct terms and pronouncing the words correctly goes a long way toward communicating accurately, which means getting your questions answer (here and everywhere in life), quickly and correctly. It may also help when shopping, as some unscrupulous dealers may decide to raise prices on the spot to take advantage of "this guy who doesn't know what he's talking about". ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear of what you are planning.  You mention a "breaker box" between the shed and main feed (presumably from your house) Is that a sub-panel as well?

I believe the short answer is "YES" you can run 6/3 from the 50 amp sub to your hot tub. The important part is proper over-current protection for the wiring and, since it's hard wired, the device (the hot tub). Heck, you could run 2 ga copper as long as the breaker was appropriate for the device.  You'd have to rob Fort Knox to pay for 2 ga copper, but that's a different issue!

I may get snipped for this, but most hot tub feeds are over-subscribed by a substantial margin.  You'd have to be running all the pump jets as well as the heater to even come close to 50 amps.

So I think your plan is good, but let's wait until others with more experience have a chance to chime in.

Comment: The pump jets don't take much, water is easy to move horizontally.  The real load is the heater.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   Agreed with that, but doing research show that the pumps can draw as much as 1,500 watts (6 amps). A large hot tub might have 4 pumps (mine does) for a total of 24 amps.   The heaters vary a lot (1,500 watts - 6,000 watts), the most typical heater is 4,500 watts, but assuming 6,000 watts (that's 25 amps). That a total of 49 amps with everything running.   I'll be honest, I really doubt the pumps really take 6 amps each.  Also, some hottubs will turn off the heater when the pumps are running.